# Delete button/link inside form

Tags: forms, cakephp-2.1

I have a form for my sessions card, and I would like to configure the delete link.
I think that I could do it with a get request at the end of each row..
However, in cakephp 2.. it "suggests" that its better to use a post request.

That's ok :

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->postLink(
                    '<button class="btn btn-danger">
                         <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
                     </button>',
                    array(
                          'action'   => 'deleteBasket', $plaque['id']
                          ),
                    array(
                          'class'    => 'tip',
                          'escape'   => false, 
                          'confirm'  => 'Are you sure ?'
                         ));
?>
```

Except that when I use this code, it generate a form inside my form so when I submit it's screwed up. I can't put this outside of my row .
Any ideas ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Reading the docs, http://api20.cakephp.org/class/form-helper#method-FormHelperpostLink

```
This method creates a <form> element. So do not use this method inside an existing form. Instead you should add a submit button using FormHelper::submit()
```

Comment: That URL shows: *"**Service Unavailable** The service is temporarily unavailable. Please try again later."*

Answer (score 1):

Since CakePHP 2.5, you can use postLink inside form element. You have to set the option `inline` to false:

```
echo $this->Form->postLink('delete', array(
    'controller' => 'somewhere',
    'action' => 'delete',
    $deletedID
), array(
   'inline' => 'false'
));
```

...and then fetch the 'postLink' block (where the actual html form tag is) preferably in the bottom of your layout view like following

```
echo $this->fetch('postLink');
```

This solution requires enabled javascript!

[Quoting the docs:](https://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-FormHelper.html#_postLink)

`inline` - Whether or not the associated form tag should be output inline. Set to false to have the form tag appended to the 'postLink' view block. Defaults to true.

`block` - Choose a custom block to append the form tag to. Using this option will override the inline option.

(Yes, it's old topic, but since I found this researching the same problem, it would be nice to have updated answer...)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Controller Name', array('url' => `array('controller' => 'Controller Name', 'action' => 'deleteBasket', $plaque['id']))); ?>`
<?php echo $this->Form->submit(arrray('class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'value' => '<i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>', 'escape' => false, 'onclick' => 'confirm('Are you sure you want to continue')')); ?>
```